# StreamSocket reading in Metro

Tags: microsoft-metro, datareader

I am working with StreamSockets in a Windows 8 Metro App and want to use a DataReader to read the incoming data. Is there any specific pattern or model I should be using to read from the socket that will allow me to read all the data available in the network buffer at any moment?

Currently, I understand I need to make calls to DataReader.LoadAsync() and then DataReader.Read…(). I want to be able to read everything that is present network buffer at any moment. My problem arises when I want to detect the end of incoming message. If I try to use a loop to continuously call LoadAsync, it will block when it reaches the end of the network buffer. I know in .NET 4.0, there is a NetworkStream class that provides a field DataAvailable that tells me if there is any data present in the network buffer so I can keep on looping until this flag is false. Is there any way to do something similar that will allow me to consume all the data available in the network buffer without having to block for a long time?

Answer (score 0):

Set DataReader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial.  This will your *await* (your task) to return before the buffer you've provided is entirely filled.

```
using(DataReader inputStream = new DataReader(this.connection.InputStream))
{
    inputStream.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
    DataReaderLoadOperation loadOperation = inputStream.LoadAsync(2500);
    await loadOperation;
    if(loadOperation.Status != AsyncStatus.Completed)
    {
        this.Disconnect();  //insert your handler here
        return;
    }

    //read complete message
    uint byteCount = inputStream.UnconsumedBufferLength;

    byte [] bytes = new byte[byteCount];
    inputStream.ReadBytes(bytes);

    this.handleServerMessage(bytes);  //insert your handler here

    //detach stream so that it won't be closed when the datareader is disposed later
    inputStream.DetachStream();                
}
```